# Mysql- “FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK” started automatically

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I would like to understand how this happened. I was running a query that would take a long time, but should not lock up any table. However, my dbs were practically down - it seems like it was being locked up by "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK"

03:21:31 select type_id, count(*) from guid_target_infos group by type_id
02:38:11 select type_id, count(*) from guid_infos group by type_id
02:24:29 FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK

But i did not start this command. can someone tell me why it was started automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that was probably a backup script running from cron. "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK". This is especially used in backups to filesystems with snapshots. More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html).

Comment: Interesting! But typically this runs w no problems. Why would it cause a lock up in the exact same time as my big select statement?

Comment: my question is: do you have some kind of script running from cron that mighy be flushing tables with read lock?